Vue 3 onMounted not loading data in Vuetify data table server
I have created this page with Vue 3 + Vuetify called demo.vue in my project which receives data from an API server.
The problem that I'm facing is that I set up the data inside an onMounted function, and once everything is loaded, data is not available in the table.
The most curious thing is that If I use await demo() outside an onMounted function, data loads perfectly on the table. So I don't really get the point of how onMounted really works. It's supposed to load the data once the component is mounted.
Data comes perfectly.
Data object OK
Error comes as NULL
Loading comes as False
Using onMounted

Not using onMounted

What is wrong?
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import DataTableComponent from '@/components/DataTableComponent'
  import useFetch from '@/hooks/useFetch'
  import buildUrl from '@/utils/urlBuilder'

  // Reactive variables
  const dataTableHeaders = ref([])
  const dataTableItems = ref([])
  const dataTableTotalItems = ref(0)
  const dataTableLoading = ref(true)

  // Methods
  let dataTableUpdate = () => {}

  const setUp = async () => {
    const url = buildUrl('fieldeas_tracktrace_pre', 'test')
    const { data, error, loading, refresh } = await useFetch(url)

    console.log("buildUrl", url)
    console.log("useFetch", data, error, loading, refresh)

    if (data && data.fields && data.rows && data.rowCount) {
      dataTableHeaders.value = data.fields
      dataTableItems.value = data.rows
      dataTableTotalItems.value = data.rowCount
    }

    dataTableLoading.value = loading
    dataTableUpdate = refresh
  }

  // On component mount
  onMounted(async () => {
    await setUp()
  })
</script>

<template>
  <v-container>
    <DataTableComponent
      :headers="dataTableHeaders"
      :items="dataTableItems"
      :totalItems="dataTableTotalItems"
      :loading="dataTableLoading"
      :update="dataTableUpdate"
    ></DataTableComponent>
  </v-container>
</template>

UPDATED
I got to solve the problem I had but another question comes to my mind:
Is this the best way to solve this problem?
The solution was to implement some watchers inside the DataTableComponent but, since the variables are reactive... it shouldn't be like that, should be?
I updated the demo.vue and I attach my useFetch and DataTableComponent files
useFetch.js
import validateParams from '@/utils/validateParams'

async function fetching(url, options) {
  const response = await fetch(url, options)

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching data: ${response.statusText}`)
  }

  const data = await response.json()

  return data
}

export default async function useFetch(url, options = {}){
  validateParams({
    url: { value: url, type: 'string' },
    options: { value: options, type: 'object' }
  })

  let data, error = null
  let loading = true

  const refresh = async () => {
    try {
      data = await fetching(url, options)
    } catch (err) {
      error = err.toString()
    } finally {
      loading = false
    }
  }

  await refresh()

  return {
    data,
    error,
    loading,
    refresh
  }
}

DataTableComponent.vue
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

  // Props
  const props = defineProps({
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    totalItems: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    update: {
      type: [Function, Promise],
      default: () => {}
    }
  })

  // Reactive variables
  const currentPage = ref(1)
  const itemsPerPage = ref(10)
  const itemsPerPageOptions = ref([
    {value: 10, title: '10'},
    {value: 25, title: '25'},
    {value: 50, title: '50'},
    {value: 100, title: '100'}
  ])
  const headers = ref([])
  const items = ref([])
  const totalItems = ref(0)
  const loading = ref(true)

  const parsedHeaders = ref([])
  const parsedItems = ref([])

  // Methods
  let refresh = () => {}

  const parseHeaders = (headers) => {
    const parsedHeaders = []

    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      const item = headers[i]
      parsedHeaders.push({
        title: item.name,
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        key: item.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '')
      })
    }

    return parsedHeaders
  }

  const parseItems = (items, headers) => {
    const parsedItems = []

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const row = items[i]
      const item = {}

      for (let z = 0; z < headers.length; z++) {
        item[headers[z].key] = row[z]
      }

      parsedItems.push(item)
    }

    return parsedItems
  }

  const parseData = () => {
    if (props.headers.length > 0 && props.items.length > 0) {
      parsedHeaders.value = parseHeaders(props.headers)
      parsedItems.value = parseItems(props.items, parsedHeaders.value)
    }
  }

  const paginateData = (items) => {
    let paginatedData = []

    if(items.length > 0){
      const start = (currentPage.value - 1) * itemsPerPage.value
      const end = start + itemsPerPage.value
      paginatedData = items.slice(start, end)
    }

    return paginatedData
  }

  const setData = () => {
    headers.value = parsedHeaders.value
    items.value = paginateData(parsedItems.value)
    totalItems.value = props.totalItems
    loading.value = props.loading
    refresh = props.update
  }

  const forceRefresh = () => {
    // Have to work on this func
    refresh()
    parseData()
    setData()
  }

  // Watchers
  watch(() => [props.headers, props.items], parseData, { immediate: true })
  watch(() => [props.totalItems, props.loading], setData, { immediate: true })
</script>

<template>
  <v-data-table-server
    v-model:page="currentPage"
    v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :items-per-page-options="itemsPerPageOptions"
    items-per-page-text=""
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :items-length="totalItems"
    :loading="loading"
    loading-text="Cargando... Por favor espera"
    no-data-text="No hay datos disponibles"
    @update:options="setData"
  >
  </v-data-table-server>
  <!-- <v-btn @click="forceRefresh" :loading="loading">forceRefresh</v-btn> -->
</template>


what other debugging have you done?  is dataTableItems set correctly?  Since you're using custom component <DataTableComponent>, the problem may be internal to it but we don't know anything about how it works. Is the items props being set?  Does items then get used directly by v-data-table or is there some intermediate step?  Please show all relevant code. The issue could be explained by reactivity not set up properly between parent component and underlying v-data-table element.
